# Codeigniter - passagem de array para controler

Tags: codeigniter, controller

Boa tarde a todos, estou com um problema em meu código e gostaria de uma ajuda para resolvê-lo. Funciona assim: recebo de um formulário 3 variáveis (id_evento, qualidade_usuario e id_usuario - esse último vem de um multiple select com o name=usuario_id[]).

Fiz o teste com o console e quando selecione no multiple select no formulário, as informações no POST vêm corretas (usuario_id[] = 1 e usuario_id[] = 2, quando seleciono dois usuários, por exemplo).

A questão é que quando recebo essas informações no controller e  jogo no foreach para que cada usuario recebido seja inserido no banco de dados, só 1 deles é adicionado.

Código da função no controller que recebe os dados do formulário:

```
public function gerarCertificado(){
    if(esta_logado()){
        $usuario = $this->session->userdata("usuario_logado");

        $id_evento = $this->input->post('id_evento');
        $evento = $this->EventosModel->buscarEvento($id_evento);
        $dadosEvento = array('evento' => $evento);
        $qualidade = $this->input->post('qualidade');

        $id_usuarios_selecionados = $this->input->post('id_usuario');

        foreach ($id_usuarios_selecionados as $id_user) {
            $existeCert = $this->UsuariosModel->verificarCertificado($id_user, $id_evento);
            // usuario selecionado já possui certificado
            if($existeCert){ 
                $this->session->set_flashdata("danger", "Algum dos usuários selecionados já possui certificado para este evento");
                redirect('/eventos/certificados/' . $id_evento);
            // usuario selecionado não possui certificado no evento escolhido --> inserir na tabela certificados
            }else{

                if($this->UsuariosModel->gerarCertificado($id_evento, $id_user, $qualidade)){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "Certificados gerados!");

                }else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("danger", "Erro ao gerar certificados!");
                }
                redirect('/eventos/certificados/' . $id_evento);
            }
        }
    }else{
        redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Código da função no model que insere no BD:

```
public function gerarCertificado($id_evento, $id_user, $qualidade){
    if($this->db->query("insert into certificados (id_evento, id_usuario, qualidade) values ('".$id_evento."','".$id_user."','".$qualidade."')")){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Resumindo, quando seleciono mais de 1 usuário no select, a função só é executada 1 com 1 dos usuários selecionados.

Obrigado!

Comment: `print_r($id_usuarios_selecionados)` mostra o quê?

Comment: porque não usa $this->db->insert('SUA_TABELA', $SUA_ARRAY)?

Answer (score 0):

Na tua explicação referente a uma caixa de selecção com o nome "usuário_id[]", mas no teu código tens:

```
$id_usuarios_selecionados = $this->input->post('id_usuario');
```

Penso que deveria ser:

```
$id_usuarios_selecionados = $this->input->post('usuário_id');
```

Bom, de qualquer maneira, penso que o problema possa estar nos redirect que tens no loop foreach, pois se um usuário tiver, ou não, certificado, existe um redirecionamento para uma outra página. O que implica que só um registo seja tratado, independentemente de quantos tiveres selecionados.

Na minha interpretação, deves passar o redirect para depois do loop foreach, assim (também dei um jeito nas flash_messages):

```
foreach ($id_usuarios_selecionados as $id_user) {
    $existeCert = $this->UsuariosModel->verificarCertificado($id_user, $id_evento);
    // usuario selecionado já possui certificado
    if($existeCert){ 
        $this->session->set_flashdata("danger", "Algum dos usuários selecionados já possui certificado para este evento");
        // usuario selecionado não possui certificado no evento escolhido --> inserir na tabela certificados
    } elseif(!$this->UsuariosModel->gerarCertificado($id_evento, $id_user, $qualidade)){
        $this->session->set_flashdata("danger", "Erro ao gerar certificados!");

        // pela tua lógica, vamos parar o loop no primeiro erro que obtivermos, aquando a criação de um certificado novo
        break;
    }
}

$this->session->set_flashdata("success", "Certificados gerados!");

redirect('/eventos/certificados/' . $id_evento);
```